# Finding a dictionary item that is within a list

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

Hi I am trying to find the best way to access a dictionary value that is within a list, , I have an Account class which I am trying to embed a Customer in using composition. Once I embed the customer I want to append all instances created into a list. Finally I would like to find a way to Get the values of the each customer from this list.

When I run the `accountList` I get

`[{'customer': {'name': 'Foo'}}, {'customer': {'name': 'bar'}}]`

I would like to find a way to access each customer from this `accountList`

I'v tried list comprehension like so `[d for d in Account.accountList if d["name"] == "smith"]`

But it doesn't seem to work as i get an empty list is an output []

The Code

```
class Customer:


  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name

  def __repr__(self):
     return repr(self.__dict__)

class Account:

  accountList = []
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.customer = Customer(name)
    Account.accountList.append(self)

  def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.__dict__)

  def __getitem__(self, i):
    return i
```

Answer (score 3):

Your list comprehension is close, but instead you would need to check one more level down, because each list item `d` is a `dict`, and the value corresponding to the key `'customer'` is itself another `dict`.

```
[d for d in Account.accountList if d['customer']['name'] == 'smith']
```

Comment: Ok thanks sounds right but when I try it out in shell I get a TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Can you `print(type(accountList))`? If it returns `str` then you have a JSON string, and need to convert it to a Python list first. Wait scratch that, I see where the list is defined.

Comment: Does the __getitem__ method seem ok with you?

Answer (score 2):

You are working with nested dictionaries so in order to compare the `name` key, you have to step one more level down.

If you want just the values for a particular customer, you can use `dict.values` with your list comprehension like so:

```
[vals for vals in d.values() for d in Account.accountList if d['customer']['name'] == 'Foo']
```

In this case, you would get a result like this:

```
[{'name': 'Foo'}]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but it comes with a NameError: name 'd' is not defined, am i missing something

Comment: Try this instead: `[vals for d in Account.accountList for vals in d.values() if d['customer']['name'] == 'Foo']`

Comment: This version throws up an Attribute Error: 'Account' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0):

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

class Account:

    accountList = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.customer = Customer(name)
        Account.accountList.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return i

Account('Jenny')
Account('John')
Account('Bradley')

print [d for d in Account.accountList if d.customer.name == 'Jenny']
```